# Performance ao comparar campos Varchar no SQL Server

Tags: sql, desempenho

A `SQL` abaixo está causando muita lentidão pelo fato de eu usar o

```
Right(L.nrDiscado, Len(D.Descricao))
```

**(acredito eu)** para comparar com o campo `D.Descricao`:

```
create table #TempNrDiscado (NrDiscado varchar(150))

Insert into #TempNrDiscado
Select distinct L.nrDiscado from #TempLigacoes L with(nolock) 
   inner join GI_Dispositivo D with(nolock) on  
      Right(L.nrDiscado, Len(D.Descricao)) = D.Descricao
```

Alguém sabe alguma forma que eu poderia fazer essa comparação?

Observação: se eu colocar um número 10 no lugar do `Len(D.Descricao) (Right(L.nrDiscado, Len(10))` ***ele vai rápido***.

Comment: Comparação entre textos (`string`) são mais demoradas, e no seu caso tem dois complicadores as duas funções (`RIGHT` e `LEN`) torna o processo mais custoso, tem também um problema talvez, porque não comparar esse INNER JOIN pela chave que seria o correto, você mesmo comprovou que colocando o número 10 o processo flui melhor. Pergunto porque juntar com textos qual é o cenário?

Comment: Se o campo só vai ser buscado desta forma, pode ser o caso de criar uma coluna/índice mais adequado pra busca e (apesar de parecer estranho) armazenar invertido. Assim, as buscas vão usar índice, e um LIKE com % na direita resolve. Agora, se quer algo mais tradicional, seria legal [edit] a pergunta e dar mais detalhes das estruturas dos dados e dos requisitos da aplicação.

Comment: Se eu colocar o 10 no lugar do Len(), o resultado é na hora!

Comment: Só pra complementar, se os dados são UTF-8 tanto o len quanto o right são obrigados a varrer todas as strings do começo ao fim, e isso custa caro. Nessas horas o pessoal que fala mal de ISO some :)

Comment: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-indexes/sql-server-indexes-on-computed-columns/

Answer (score 0):

acabei resolvendo isso tendo que trabalhar com algumas tabelas temporárias afim de obter um único valor para fazer o JOIN ao invés do Right(L.nrDiscado, Len(D.Descricao)) conforme dito aqui que causa muita lentidão.

A questão de trabalhar com a chave conforme foi dito aqui também, não é possível nesse caso, pois a forma de vínculo das informações é somente dessa forma.

Agradeço a todos pela ajuda!